# Inspect CGColorSpace ICC color profile data on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, gamma, color-profile

I'm looking for a way to inspect the the ICC color profile data provided [`CGColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace)'s [`copyICCData()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace/1644732-copyiccdata) method.

Specifically, I'm loading PNG images into [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage)s on iOS, and trying to find a way to use the `let iccData:CFData? = aUIImage.cgImage!.colorSpace!.copyICCData()` to determine the gamma for the image file.  This is for a game that uses 3D rendering— if the source image has a standard 2.2 gamma, I'll load the image data into a texture as sRGB *(e.g. `MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm_sRGB`)* and if it has a gamma of 1.0 I'll instead load it as a linear texture *(e.g. `MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm`)*.

*Note: The solution of just passing a `UIImage`/`CGImage` to the rendering system (SceneKit/Metal) and letting it sort it out won't work here because: 1. Some of the rendering I'm doing is assembling 2D images into a 3D texture, so that's something I need to do with raw data, not something I can just read from a standard image file format; 2. I'm specifically trying to pass gamma-1.0 images into the rendering system to avoid the overhead of sRGB→linear conversion (rendering is in linear space).*

*Also: Manual ICC-parsing solutions, Apple-API-using solutions, and open-source library suggestions are all acceptable answers.  This is not specifically a query for tool recommendation — any solution that'll work is a good one — but in my research, manual ICC parsing would be unwieldy and Apple's APIs don't seem to expose any ICC properties.  So I believe the most likely answer is a pointer to some library out there that I haven't been able to find via Google or GitHub or CocoaPods or StockOverflow, and will be gladly accepted.*

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use sample icc 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/sampleicc/'. Just get the profile data as you described, then use OpenIccProfile to load it up. From there, get a ref to the header structure (.m_Header) and pull the info you need. I'd also recommend you take a look at RefIccMax 'https://github.com/InternationalColorConsortium/RefIccMAX' which is a newer version of the same lib, but not ready for primetime.